# What is appropriate HTTP error code if user try to perform action not available for they

Tags: rest, http, http-error, error-code

I have issue with HTTP code response.

**Use case:**
User with user try to modify record which is available to edit only for users with moderator privileges (enforced by business logic).

What HTTP status response is expected?

I'm sure that below statuses are wrong.

- `200` is wrong because action is not success
- `400` seems to be wrong because all request parts are correct (body/headers/method)

I consider `401 Unauthorized` or `403 Forbidden`, but i don't have any argument to apply.

What status would you expect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I consider `401 Unauthorized` or `403 Forbidden`, but I don't have any argument to apply.

The [`403`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) status code seems to be suitable for the situation described in your question. However, if the server wants to "hide" the existence of a resource, then [`404`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3) can be used instead. See the following quote from the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**6.5.3.  403 Forbidden**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.5.3)
>
> The `403` (Forbidden) status code indicates that the server understood the request but refuses to authorize it.  A server that wishes to make public why the request has been forbidden can describe that reason in the response payload (if any).
>
> If authentication credentials were provided in the request, the server considers them insufficient to grant access.  The client SHOULD NOT automatically repeat the request with the same credentials.  The client MAY repeat the request with new or different credentials.  However, a request might be forbidden for reasons unrelated to the credentials.
>
> An origin server that wishes to "hide" the current existence of a forbidden target resource MAY instead respond with a status code of `404` (Not Found).

The [`401`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-3.1) status code is meant to be used for [HTTP authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235) (where the credentials are sent in the [`Authorization`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#section-4.2) header) to indicate that the credentials have been *refused* for that request.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this source. I'm completely forget about this.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect a 403. 401 is usually used for login failures and things like that, 403 for trying to do something you're not allowed to do after being logged in.